# Aauth codeigniter library, undefined constant PASSWORD_DEFAULT

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a project using the library aauth CodeIgniter. when I run on windows localhost it running as well.  when I move my project to the centos server virtualbox I just installed, I found the following error:

A PHP Error was encountered

```
Severity: Notice
Message: Use of undefined constant PASSWORD_DEFAULT - assumed
 'PASSWORD_DEFAULT'
Filename: config/aauth.php
Line Number: 136
```

any help would be great. Thank you.

Comment: The error is very specified and clear. I guess that the PHP errors setting is disabled on your local enviroment.

Comment: @NguyenThanh, thanks. but I don't know how to fix it, can you explain how to fix it?